# Cannot set Danish Keyboard for non-sudo users in xrdp

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xrdp

We have a Ubuntu 16.04.1 version at a hosting company in Germany (Contabo) and a xrdp 0.9.0 version. When we create users, it is only the `sudo` users that will have Danish keyboard in xrdp. Even though it is set to Danish...

Does anyone know what to do?